# I'm trying to install Magento2.4.5 via composer on MacOS but I got this error "Undefined variable $bestCandidate"

Tags: magento2, php-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Gcn.png)

I'm trying to install magento2.4.5 community edition but I got this error in terminal: **"Undefined variable $bestCandidate In Version.php line 49. "**

Steps that I did:

- installed PHP 8.1.18
- installed MySQL and Apache Server
- generated my private an public keys and grant access in https://marketplace.magento.com/
- installed composer
  -composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition  **Which is failing in the point above**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composer version 1x then you should update your composer version to 2. With composer 2x version installation should work for you.

For more details refer [Undefined variable $bestCandidate](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37318)